# OpenCL program works on the CPU but outputs empty image when run on the GPU

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following OpenCL Kernel, a Gaussian Blur

```
__constant sampler_t sampler =
        CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE |
        CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
        CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

__constant float gaussian_kernel[3][3] = {
    {0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f},
    {0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f},
    {0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f} };

void kernel gaussian_blur(
    read_only image2d_t input_image,
    write_only image2d_t output_image) {

    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int2 coords[9] = {
        { x - 1, y - 1 }, { x, y - 1 }, { x + 1, y - 1 },
        { x - 1, y     }, { x, y     }, { x + 1, y     },
        { x - 1, y + 1 }, { x, y + 1 }, { x + 1, y + 1 }
    };

    float4 pixel_value = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            int index = i * 3 + j;
            float4 blurred =
                as_float4(read_imageui(input_image, sampler, coords[index]));

            pixel_value.x += (blurred.x * gaussian_kernel[i][j]);
            pixel_value.y += (blurred.y * gaussian_kernel[i][j]);
            pixel_value.z += (blurred.z * gaussian_kernel[i][j]);
            pixel_value.w += (blurred.w * gaussian_kernel[i][j]);
        }
    }

    uint4 final_value = as_uint4(pixel_value);

    write_imageui(output_image, coords[4], final_value);
}
```

When I specify the device to use as the CPU, The blur works properly.  Here's the device selection code

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);

if(all_platforms.size() == 0) {
    std::cerr << "No platforms available" <<std::endl;
    exit(-1);
}

cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];

std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);

if(all_devices.size() == 0) {
    std::cerr << "No device found" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
}

cl::Device default_device = all_devices[1]; //Changing this index to 0 uses my graphics card
```

Now, if the default_device is set to the GPU, only an empty image is output by the program.  The relevant image setup code is (note that `input` is a `Magick::Image` and `in_pixels` a heap allocated array of `unsigned short`):

```
cl::ImageFormat format(CL_RGBA, CL_UNSIGNED_INT16);

cl::Image2D input_image_buffer;
input.write(0, 0, 
    input.baseColumns(), input.baseRows(), "RGBA", Magick::ShortPixel, in_pixels);

input_image_buffer = cl::Image2D(
    context, 
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
    format,
    input.baseColumns(),
    input.baseRows(),
    0,
    in_pixels,
    &cl_error);

cl::Image2D output_image_buffer;
output_image_buffer = cl::Image2D(
    context, 
    CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
    format, 
    input.baseColumns(),
    input.baseRows(),
    0,
    out_pixels,
    &cl_error);
```

And the Kernel setup/Image output code (`gaussian_program` was built without error of course)

```
cl::Kernel gaussian_kernel(gaussian_program, "gaussian_blur");

cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device, 0, &cl_error);

cl::size_t<3> origin;
cl::size_t<3> size;
origin[0] = 0;
origin[1] = 0;
origin[2] = 0;

size[0] = input.baseColumns();
size[1] = input.baseRows();
size[2] = 1;

cl_error = gaussian_kernel.setArg(0, input_image_buffer);

cl_error = gaussian_kernel.setArg(1, output_image_buffer);

cl::NDRange range(input.baseColumns(), input.baseRows());

cl_error = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
    gaussian_kernel, 
    cl::NullRange, 
    range,
    cl::NullRange);

queue.finish();

try{
    output.read(
        input.baseColumns(), 
        input.baseRows(), 
        "RGBA", Magick::ShortPixel, out_pixels);
}
catch(Magick::Exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << "A Magick error occured while writing the pixel cache: " <<
        std::endl << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

Now, I removed a lot of error checking for the purpose of this example, but the original code checks cl_error after every OpenCL call and never signals an error.  The code executes as expected on the CPU but the image is empty when the code is executed on the GPU.

I suspected a synchronization issue at first (the `queue.finish()` call is required for that precise purpose, even on the CPU) but littering the code with `cl::finish()` or `queue.finish()` calls in an attempt to serialize the execution didn't help at all.

Is there something I'm clearly doing wrong?  Is there a potential reason for this OpenCL kernel to fail on the GPU but not on the CPU?

For the record, I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 using the AMD APP SDK OpenCL implementation with a Radeon HD 7970.

Comment: as_float4 and as_uint4 are *not* conversions. They just re-interpret the bits without changing them. Use convert_float4 and convert_uint4 instead.

Comment: @EricBainville Hi there stranger!  After crying in a corner in foetal position for a few hours, I learned it's possible to add `printf` calls to a kernel.  So I started debugging using such statements and noticed the `float -> uint` conversions weren't happening as I expected.  Right as I was starting to investigate further, I saw your comment and made the fixes.  You just put an end to a couple days of misery.  If you post this comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, **as_float4** is not a conversion. It takes the 32 bits of the **uint**, and interprets them as **float** bits. In your case, you are reading 16 bits, so the float value will be a extremely small (exponent will be 0).  Use **convert_float4** instead.

The answer about not reading back the data is correct too.  You need calls to **clEnqueueReadBuffer** or **clEnqueueMapBuffer** to make sure the data is read back from the device.

Answer (score 6):

Well, where do you read the image back from your GPU?

You allocate your input image with the flag `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`

> This flag is valid only if host_ptr is not NULL. If specified, it indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to allocate memory for the memory object and copy the data from memory referenced by host_ptr.

and your output image with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`

> This flag is valid only if host_ptr is not NULL. If specified, it
>   indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use
>   memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory
>   object.
>
> OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents
>   pointed to by host_ptr in device memory. This cached copy can be used
>   when kernels are executed on a device.
>
> The result of OpenCL commands that operate on multiple buffer objects
>   created with the same host_ptr or overlapping host regions is
>   considered to be undefined.

there is nothing wrong with your allocation, however you never tell the OpenCL implementation to write the memory to the used device and to read that memory back into hosts main memory. This may work for CPUs because the memory is already in their device memory (the main memory) but fails for GPUs.

The OpenCL c++ binding offers `cl::enqueueWriteImage(/*params*/);` and `cl::enqueueReadImage(/*params*/);` to write and read image buffers to/from a device.

Comment: When using integrated gpu's, a copy is needed like this?

Comment: A copy is always needed. However under some conditions, it is a NOP because the source and destiny is the same (CPU->CPU).

Comment: Very good point.  The way I interpreted the API was that specifying `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` or `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` when creating the image would perform the write or reads automatically and that simply calling `cl::finish()` would force the synchronization.  It's not the case and adding the proper writes and reads now works correctly on the CPU and returns a fully black (as opposed to transparent before) image when run on the GPU.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866942/enqueuewriteimage-fail-on-gpu leads me to suspect a driver bug.  I'll report back when I find the cause.